# How to Test/Run Azure Functions in Private network

Tags: azure-functions

I have Azure Function in private network. I would like to test with "Test/Run" on "Code + Test" page of Function.

I got Web App - Unavailable

```
You must have direct network access in order to run your function. Your app may be restricted with Private Endpoints, Access Restrictions or Service Endpoints.
```

Is it possible to configure somehow that I would use Test/Run?

Comment: You can refer to a similar issue: [Azure Function Test/Run returns 'You must have direct network access in order to run your function'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/120532/azure-function-testrun-returns-39you-must-have-dir.html)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I only had to set a VNet integration, and allow public access in Access Restriction.

Comment: This worked in my scenario. We put our Function application behind a private endpoint which ended up enabling Access Restriction which was denying all public access. This broke our web deploy process as well as our code + test ability. Turning off Access Restriction brought back access to those features.

Answer (score 0):

We generally get this error message when a azure functions setup with private site access which isn't allowing the calls to the functions.
You can refer to this MS Docs to understand more about manually running [Non HTTP triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http) function.

And as from DeepDave comment suggested like we can whitelist any of the used Azure IP which is in connect with the functions app.